# How to compile redis static binary for docker image FROM scratch

Tags: docker, gcc, redis, compilation

I am trying to build something that can be called a redis scratch/distroless docker image. The final image should only contains

- `redis.conf` configuration file
- `redis-server` binary

I am using a multistage Dockerfile.

```
FROM gcc:10 AS builder

RUN wget https://download.redis.io/releases/redis-stable.tar.gz && \
    tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz && \
    cd redis-stable && \
    make CFLAGS="-static" EXEEXT="-static" LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/"

FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder /redis-stable/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
COPY --from=builder /redis-stable/src/redis-server /bin/redis-server

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/redis-server"]
```

If I dive my image, it contains only what I was expecting

```
├── bin
│   └── redis-server
└── etc
    └── redis
        └── redis.conf
```

As my image is going go be running from scratch, I am building redis binary as a static, including all needed libraries.

When I docker run the image, I get the following

```
exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

After some [google](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2020/02/01/quest-minimal-docker-images-part-1/), I have notice some dynamic library is missing.

I am no expert in c nor gcc. But I was under the impression that using `make CFLAGS="-static" EXEEXT="-static" LDFLAGS="-I/`
instead of a single `make`
would do the trick of making a binary with everything needed inside

Please note this error is not because the entrypoint path is incorrect. If you use for instance

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/redis-serverrrrr"]
```

you get the following error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/redis-serverrrrr": stat /bin/redis-serverrrrr: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

Also If I change the running image from

```
FROM scrath
```

to

```
FROM centos:8
```

after a docker run the container starts OK, so the building process seems to be OK

I have no idea how to build a static binary of redis, google has given me no answer, maybe it is not possible. Otherwise this whole adventure may have no sense, so any feedback is really wellcome.

I have not tested it, but I believe if I `ldd` the binary and copy files so files one by one to the running image it may work. But I believe that is not a very clean solution. But maybe, this is the way.

Comment: Is this just for learning purposes? The redis-alpine image is a total of ~10MB. I think that will be pretty hard to beat.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you, but I am trying this for learning purposes. Although maybe someone would suggest scratch images provide lesser attack surface than alpine ones. But that, IMHO, is another question for another day.

Comment: Add `-static` to your `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Using `LDFLAGS="-static -I/usr/local/include/"` or `LDFLAGS="-static"` gives the same error: `exec user process caused: no such file or directory`.

Comment: @usuario weird. When I add it, I can get Redis to start and `ldd` shows no dependencies.

Comment: @HansKilian, sorry it is working like you said. I think I had a problem with docker cache when building the image. Please, can you elaborate an answer? so I can accept it.